# Self-excluding classes from PhpStorm index

Tags: php, indexing, phpstorm

I have multiple projects where I generate classes programmatically, but sometimes they are just base classes (contains only the build information) extended by other classes for further use. I want to exclude them from PhpStorm index.

Is there any way to do it with any comment / custom PHPDoc / other stuff? I can't do and don't want at all to do by myself in all project every time with the folder right click option. Because of they are auto generated, also not a practical solution if I do it by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, this might be your only way to do it programaticaly

Update your script that generates them to also add their entries to
`./.idea/<project_name.iml>` - it is just an xml file

```xml
<component name="NewModuleRootManager">
  <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
    <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/<target_dir_path>" />
    <!-- ... -->
    </content>
</component>
```

Comment: Thank you! It's enough for me. I would add that the status of the directories automatically updated when an external source modifies the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that using comments or other in-editor features, but you can add them to "Ignored Files and Folders" list at *File | Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Editor | File Types*, if they have some common naming pattern.

[image]

See also https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/creating-and-registering-file-types.html#ignore-files-folders

Comment: Thanks, but I need a solution where I can do it without manual tasks.